# QComboBox has unexpected behavior when changing stylesheets while Qt.UIEffect.UI_AnimateCombo is set to False

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

My goal was to make a combo box which shows the down arrow only when the mouse is hovering above it. To do that I subclassed QComboBox and reimplemented enterEvent and leaveEvent which would change its stylesheet accordingly. It works just as expected, when to window shows up, down arrow is hidden and when the mouse hovers above combo box, the down arrow shows up. Then, when the mouse clicks on combo box text, the drop down list shows up and the down arrow becomes invisible again (which I can deal with, but if someone has a solution I'm all ears). The main problem is when the mouse clicks on the drop down arrow, instead of just hiding the drop down arrow, as it did when mouse clicked on the text, it also hides the text along with the drop down arrow. I did some testing to find out what's causing the problem and it seems that calling setEffectEnabled(Qt.UIEffect.UI_AnimateCombo, False) on QApplication is the issue, although I have no idea how disabling drop down animation is related to making text disappear when clicking on drop down arrow. Also, if someone has more elegant way of doing what I want, again, I'm all ears :). Here's the example code:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QEnterEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QComboBox, QWidget


class TestComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.default_stylesheet = ''' 
        QComboBox {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
            background-color: white;
            min-width: 150px;
        }'''

        self.hide_down_arrow_stylesheet = '''QComboBox::down-arrow { \
                                             background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}'''

        self.setStyleSheet(self.default_stylesheet + self.hide_down_arrow_stylesheet)

    def enterEvent(self, event: QEnterEvent) -> None:
        self.setStyleSheet(self.default_stylesheet)
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event: QEvent) -> None:
        self.setStyleSheet(self.default_stylesheet + self.hide_down_arrow_stylesheet)
        super().leaveEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.combobox = TestComboBox(self.widget)
        self.combobox.resize(180, 30)
        self.combobox.insertItem(0, "item 1")
        self.combobox.insertItem(0, "item 2")

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setEffectEnabled(Qt.UIEffect.UI_AnimateCombo, False)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably some internal and complex bug related to the fact that you only have set a *single* sub-control property, but the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls) specifically addresses this aspect:

> **Note:** With complex widgets such as QComboBox and QScrollBar, if one property or sub-control is customized, **all** the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well.

Be aware that in most cases, this is also related to the fact that no [layout manager](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) was set, and in most of my tests the problem automatically disappears as long as a proper layout is used (as you ***always*** should, even if you're using only one child widget).

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox)
```

Now, I was able to still reproduce the problem under certain conditions, even with a layout. This is due to what was explained in the beginning: if you set a property of a complex widget, you have to set all of them; failing to do so might result in unexpected behavior.

In this specific case, I believe that the QStyleSheetStyle (which is a private style automatically set on any widget that is affected by a QSS, including inherited ones) fails to restore the painter's pen, and it uses the arrow's color for the combo label, but it does so only under certain (possibly, "random") conditions.

The point remains: there are properties that are not set, specifically the `drop-down` pseudo element.
A consequence of this is that setting the `border` for that pseudo element results in resetting the arrow image to a blank one, but we can use that as an actual advantage; since we know that setting a border results in a no arrow image, we can update the style sheet accordingly:

```
class TestComboBox(QComboBox):
    default_stylesheet = ''' 
        TestComboBox {
            color: black;
            selection-color: black;
        }
        
        TestComboBox QAbstractItemView {
            background-color: white;
            min-width: 150px;
        }
        '''

    non_hover_stylesheet = '''
        TestComboBox::drop-down {
            border: none;
        }
        '''

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setHoverState(False)

    def setHoverState(self, state):
        qss = self.default_stylesheet
        if not state:
            qss += self.non_hover_stylesheet
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super().enterEvent(event)
        self.setHoverState(True)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super().leaveEvent(event)
        self.setHoverState(False)
```

Further notes:

- I removed the `selection-background-color` and `background-color` properties, as they result in an inconsistent behavior with certain styles (specifically, the "Fusion" style, which is considered the reference one for QSS and should *always* be checked) because those properties are often used ignoring the alpha level; I cannot test it with the "WindowsVista" style, but the point remains: if you want a transparent background color, it **must** be consistent with the actual background; consider using the QApplication's [`palette()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#palette) to get the colors of `Highlight` and `HighlightedText` roles, and eventually use those colors (without the alpha level) to set the actual backgrounds;
- I made the QSS "templates" as class attributes: since we can assume that the stylesheet is set as a class default, defining it as an instance attribute makes little sense;
- this obviously does *not* (nor can) consider *inherited* stylesheets; while I specifically used the `TestComboBox` class selector instead of `QComboBox`, but remember that if you set a stylesheet (that *expands* other QComboBox properties or pseudo elements/states) to any parent or the application, you may get inconsistent and unexpected behavior;
- (unrelated, but still important) it's good practice to *not* call `self.show()` (or `self.setVisible(True)`) within the `__init__` of a widget;

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Although layout wasn't really the issue here (I had my combo box in a layout before I isolated it from the rest of my main code when making the example code), I managed to fix the issue  in a few tries by just reading the documentation more closely.  Also, if there were at least 2 widgets in the example, I would've used layouts to organize them.

Comment: @N1teShad0w you should use layout managers even when you just have a single widget. Layouts don't exist only to "organize widgets", but are fundamental for proper widget size management: the layout ensures that all children have proper geometries, and that the parent is able to correctly show them by respecting all size hints and policies. As soon as I put the combo in a layout, the problem disappeared (I specifically addressed *this* case), but, as said, it could be due to a combination of aspects. If you found the proper solution, please add your own answer.

Comment: I get what you're saying, although in this case the widget has a fixed size and, at least on my end, adding it to the a layout hasn't changed anything. I posted the solution below, although it's still buggy, it works when I run it on its own but not when I try implementing TestComboBox in my main code (even though everything in there is in a layout). What happens is that everything is invisible at first and everything shows on hover (both the text and drop down arrow), but once an item is selected it works like its supposed to.

Comment: @N1teShad0w I've updated the answer, I believe it should work as expected now, but I cannot test it on modern Windows systems. Please let me know if it works as it should.

Comment: It works perfectly! I added `selection-background-color` and `background-color`, tested it with "Fusion" style as well and it seemed fine, still working as expected although I will implement your in idea in that note, if my addition causes some unwanted behavior in the future, since I'm not yet focused on stylizing my whole application, but adding more features to it before I make it actually look nice. I don't intend to make it inherit stylesheets, but thanks for the note about that anyways :) (who knows what I might do in the future)

Comment: @N1teShad0w It's possible that the background color behavior is slightly different on other OS, but you still need to consider the base color (without alpha) which should *not* be the same as the opaque one; also note that setting hardcoded colors on complex widgets requires special care: you either ensure that you set **all** colors, or you use colors based on the current system palette, otherwise elements could become invisible (for instance, if the OS uses a dark mode).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will focus more on that when I start making more styles for my application, then I will test it on both win10 and ubuntu 20.04 since I have dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by reading through the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls. Here's the solution:

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QComboBox, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class TestComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.default_stylesheet = ''' 
        QComboBox {
            color: black;
            selection-color: black;
            selection-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        
        QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
            background-color: white;
            min-width: 150px;
        }
        
        QComboBox:!hover::down-arrow {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        '''

        self.setStyleSheet(self.default_stylesheet)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        self.combobox = TestComboBox()
        self.combobox.resize(180, 30)
        self.combobox.insertItem(0, "item 1")
        self.combobox.insertItem(0, "item 2")
        self.combobox.insertItem(0, "item 3")
        self.combobox.insertItem(0, "item 4")
        self.combobox.insertItem(0, "item 5")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combobox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setEffectEnabled(Qt.UIEffect.UI_AnimateCombo, False)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: With this code I get an inconsistent behavior with Oxygen style and a completely black combo (until the drop down is opened) with fusion style, probably due to the background-colors: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` is still black even if it's transparent, and the non-alpha background is used for gradients in certain styles, so you should probably use `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)`. I will investigate more on this, but consider the possibility that this might not be manageable with stylesheets if you still want the default arrow, so you might need to opt for a custom arrow image, or override it with QStyle.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the advice! I won't be implementing custom arrow images yet, since I have some other more important things to focus on in my project right now. I'm using windowsvista style and it works like I described in my last comment on the post above. Still far from perfect, but I will return to it at a later time (in a few days or so, maybe even earlier), because, as I said, I have a lot of things to work on. Although, if you manage to find out something, I'm all ears :)

Comment: Ok, remember that it's usually better to always check with multiple styles when using stylesheets, especially for complex widgets, with "Fusion" tests almost mandatory (which is considered the most "common" ground and usually QSS compliant). Btw, you said that the combo has a fixed size, but you only called `resize()` (which is irrelevant if layouts are in use), and in any case fixed sizes with arbitrary values should *always* be avoided, as you can never be sure about user settings - specifically custom font and font scaling.